# Android : How to use Wiki tude framework without use their .apk?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, wikitude

I download demo application from wikitude and it works, but I need to set up their wikitude browser .apk .

Does it has anyway that be able use Augmented reality without use their .apk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it have anyway by which one can use Augmented reality without using their .apk

[As per the Wikitude sdk doc](http://www.wikitude.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Wikitude_SDK_1.1.2_Documentation.pdf), you will need `wikitudesdk.jar`

---

As per the comment from WikiTude - a lot has changed since - [See the WikeTude documentation for Android](http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation/android)

Comment: The referenced document above does not exist anymore. The Wikitude SDK as of now can run without the Wikitude App installed and has evolved quite a lot. You can read about the Wikitude SDK [here](http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk) or go straight to the [Android documentation for the SDK](http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation/android)